# Using alternative event loop without setting global policy

Tags: python-asyncio, uvloop

I'm using `uvloop` with [`websockets`](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as

```
import uvloop
coro = websockets.serve(handler, host, port)  # creates new server
loop = uvloop.new_event_loop()
loop.create_task(coro)
loop.run_forever()
```

It works fine, I'm just wondering whether I could run to some unexpected problems without setting the global `asyncio` policy to `uvloop`. As far as I understand, not setting the global policy should work as long as nothing down there doesn't use the global `asyncio` methods, but works with the passed-down event loop directly. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't have any particular reasons to do it like this, I just don't like the global aspect of asyncio, because it makes it feel more like a language platform than an async library. And I like to think of it as the the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three main global objects in asyncio:

- the policy (common to all threads)
- the default loop (specific to the current thread)
- the running loop (specific to the current thread)

All the attempts to get the current context in asyncio go through a single function, [asyncio.get_event_loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.get_event_loop).

One thing to remember is that [since Python 3.6](https://github.com/python/asyncio/pull/452) (and Python 3.5.3+), `get_event_loop` has a specific behavior:

- If it's called while a loop is running (e.g within a coroutine), the running loop is returned.
- Otherwise, the default loop is returned by the policy.

## Example 1:

```
import uvloop
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_forever()
```

Here the policy is the uvloop policy. The loop returned by `get_event_loop` is a uvloop, and it is set as the default loop for this thread. When this loop is running, it is registered as the running loop.

In this example, calling `get_event_loop()` anywhere in this thread returns the right loop.

## Example 2:

```
import uvloop
loop = uvloop.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_forever()
```

Here the policy is still the default policy. The loop returned by `new_event_loop` is a uvloop, and it is set as the default loop for this thread explicitly using `asyncio.set_event_loop`. When this loop is running, it is registered as the running loop.

In this example, calling `get_event_loop()` anywhere in this thread returns the right loop.

## Example 3:

```
import uvloop
loop = uvloop.new_event_loop()
loop.run_forever()
```

Here the policy is still the default policy. The loop returned by `new_event_loop` is a uvloop, but it is not set as the default loop for this thread. When this loop is running, it is registered as the running loop.

In this example, calling `get_event_loop()` within a coroutine returns the right loop (the running uvloop). But calling `get_event_loop()` outside a coroutine will result in a new standard asyncio loop, set as the default loop for this thread.

**So the first two approaches are fine, but the third one is discouraged.**

Comment: Thanks for the mention of 3.6. So #3 explains why my code works even when I'm not passing the uvloop loop down to the coroutine. Is this new behaviour documented somewhere? I didn't see it when browsing the documentation. Also, if it is discouraged, why was it introduced? I understand that my (discouraged) code wouldn't work in 3.5.

Comment: Ok, I see that the discussion about get_event_loop is here https://bugs.python.org/issue28613

Comment: @azag0 Your code wouldn't work in 3.5, unless you pass the event loop explicitly everywhere (`loop=loop`) as @GerasimovMikhail pointed out.

Comment: @azag0 Also see [asyncio PR #452](https://github.com/python/asyncio/pull/452). And no, I don't think it's part of the documentation yet.

Comment: So from reading https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-tulip/yF9C-rFpiKk/tk5oA3GLHAAJ, I wouldn't say that #3 is discouraged. Contrary, the new behaviour was introduced to enable #3. It enables you to forget about the loop once you run it. In this way, it enables you to write code *as if* everything was async/await all the way down, as is for example in curio. The loop is delegated to just run your entry point coroutines and then disappears. Lower-level asyncio code can still pick it up if it needs to.

Comment: @azag0 People have different opinions about this. Mine is that relying on `get_event_loop` within coroutines is much nicer that passing the loop explicitly. However, I still think it's better to set the proper policy and use the loop provided by the policy in order to avoid unexpected problems (try to use `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` without setting the loop and you'll have a surprise).

Comment: Yes, I guess it depends on whether one's more comfortable with a global state or a runtime-defined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

### Custom event loop should be passed as param

If you want to use custom event loop without using `asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)`, you'll have to pass loop as param to every relevant asyncio coroutines or objects, for example:

```
await asyncio.sleep(1, loop=loop)
```

or

```
fut = asyncio.Future(loop=loop)
```

You may notice that probably any coroutine/object from `asyncio` module accepts this param.

Same thing is also applied to `websockets` library as you [may see](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/websockets/server.py#L448) from it's source code. So you'll need to write:

```
loop = uvloop.new_event_loop()
coro = websockets.serve(handler, host, port, loop=loop)  # pass loop as param
```

There's no guarantee that your program would work fine if you won't pass your event loop as param like that.

### Possible, but uncomfortable

While theoretically you can use some event loop without changing policy I find it's extremely uncomfortable.

- You'll have to write `loop=loop` almost everywhere, it's annoying
- There's no guarantee that some third-party would allow you to pass
  loop as param and won't just use `asyncio.get_event_loop()`

Base on that I advice you to reconsider your decision and use global event loop.

I understand that it may be felt "unright" to use global event loop, but "right" way is to pass loop as param everywhere is worse on practice (in my opinion).